# How do I safely call an async method from EF's non-async SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core, and EF Core which has `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync`.

Before saving to the database, in my `DbContext`, I perform some auditing/logging:

```
public async Task LogAndAuditAsync() {
    // do async stuff
}

public override int SaveChanges {
    /*await*/ LogAndAuditAsync();      // what do I do here???
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync {
    await LogAndAuditAsync();
    return await base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is the synchronous `SaveChanges()`.

I always do "async all the way down", but here that isn't possible. I could redesign to have `LogAndAudit()` and `LogAndAuditAsync()` but that is not DRY and I'll need to change a dozen other major pieces of code which don't belong to me.

There are lots of other questions about this topic, and all are general and complex and full of debate. *I need to know the safest approach in this specific case*.

So, in `SaveChanges()`, how do I safely and synchronously call an async method, without deadlocks?

Comment: Have you tried using of await Task.Run(() => { ... });

Comment: @H.Herzl Yes that works. But it's not that I can't get it to compile, or to run. It's that I need to know, in this particular case, what is the *safest way*, which avoids the possibility of deadlocks. It's easy to get sync-over-async very wrong.

Comment: Sidestepping the issue, is it possible to use a queue for the logging/ auditing and then the log/audit operation becomes async by nature,so you don't need async / await there at all ?

Comment: @Menahem It's a nice idea, but our system doesn't use a queue.

Comment: Well, maybe its time it did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do sync-over-async, and each has it's gotchas. But I needed to know which is the **safest for this specific use case**.

The answer is to use Stephen Cleary's ["Thread Pool Hack"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx):

```
Task.Run(() => LogAndAuditAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The reason is that within the method, only more database work is performed, nothing else. The original sychronization context is not needed - within EF Core's `DbContext` you shouldn't need access to ASP.NET Core's `HttpContext`!

Hence it is best to offload the operation to the thread pool, and avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to call an async method from a non-async method is to use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
public override int SaveChanges {
    LogAndAuditAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will ensure that an exception thrown in `LogAndAuditAsync` does not appear as an `AggregateException` in `SaveChanges`. Instead the original exception is propagated.

However, if the code is executing on a special synchronization context that may deadlock when doing sync-over-async (e.g. ASP.NET, Winforms and WPF) then you have to be more careful.

Every time the code in `LogAndAuditAsync` uses `await` it will wait for a task to complete. If this task has to execute on the synchronization context that currently is blocked by the call to `LogAndAuditAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` you have a deadlock.

To avoid this you need to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all `await` calls in `LogAndAuditAsync`. E.g.

```
await file.WriteLineAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Notice that after this `await` the code will continue executing outside the synchronization context (on the task pool scheduler).

If that is not possible your last option is to start a new task on the task pool scheduler:

```
Task.Run(() => LogAndAuditAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This will still block the synchronization context but `LogAndAuditAsync` will execute on the task pool scheduler and not deadlock because it does not have to enter the synchronization context that is blocked.

Comment: I'm aware of this syntax, but why is it the safest approach in this use case, for persistence in EF Core and ASP.NET Core? There are a number of ways to do sync-over-async, this is one of them.